# Login to MySQL from a shell script without showing password?

Tags: mysql, database-connection

I want to write a cron job that passes a shell script to log into a MySQL database and perform some queries. To connect to the database as a certain user, I wanted to know what options I have to hide or not use the password?

The kind of answer I'm looking for is the Trust Authentication in PostgreSQL using a Trust User, so that no password is required.

I know you can create a password configuration file in the server but I want something more dynamic since passwords change often.

What are my options?

Comment: hide how? so it doesn't show up on the command line?

Comment: I don't want to supply the password directly at all, if that can be done. And hide in the sense that if someone can open and read my shell script, I do not want them to be able to see the password as normal text.

Comment: well, either you configure the account to have no password at all, or you have to store the password SOMEWHERE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple task to do !! in this [link](http://www.aodba.com/main_articles_single.php?art=54&page=mysql) you will find a how to article to show you how this is done.

I will describe it here ! 
-chose the user you what to login without a password and create a file in your home directory as the one bellow called .my.cnf and alter the permission on it as **chmod 600**.
- it should do the work - i use this with my admin user.

```
[mysqldump]
user = --user used to run backup
password = --password of the user
[mysql]
user= --user used to run backup
password= --password of the user
```

---

### Example of how this works:

```
[root@BIH001 ~]# cat /root/.my.cnf
 [mysqldump]
user = root
password = ***********
[mysql]
user= adrian
password= ***********
```

---

**Next i switch to this user (adrian a SO level) :**

```
[root@BIH001 ~]# su - adrian
```

---

**And connect to mysql without password or any user :**
(sure you will have to have this account present in the database as well as he will only see what ever you give him the rights to see)

```
[adrian@BIH001 ~]$ mysql
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 962888
Server version: 5.1.69-log Source distribution

Copyright (c) 2000, 2013, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql>
```

---

**Alter the .my.cnf file and add the root user to connect without password:**

```
[root@BIH001 ~]# cat /root/.my.cnf
 [mysqldump]
user = root
password = ***********
[mysql]
user= root
password= ***********

[root@BIH001 ~]# mysql -uroot
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 963365
Server version: 5.1.69-log Source distribution

Copyright (c) 2000, 2013, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql>
```

**I hope this made it clear for you !!**

Comment: There's already a 'my.cnf' file there that doesn't have a username or password in it. Is this the same as '.my.cnf'?

Comment: Is a different one ! normally i have two - one /etc/my.cnf and one /root/.my.cnf (this one will grant access with no pass) - as the /etc/my.cnf will be written by the user who runs the mysql service and this might go worng to place a text pass in it !

Comment: I am still getting ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) even after creating the file